# How to install the Web Apps in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dpkg, webapps

Can't Install the Web Apps in Ubuntu 16.04
I tried to do this to resolve the problem
but got error message saying,

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the lock file. After that try again what you wanted to do.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Don't blindly remove lock-files without checking if others is using them, please follow the link provided by @muru in the comment to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Remove your `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

after this run `sudo apt-get update.`

It should work fine now.

Comment: Don't blindly remove lock-files without checking if others is using them. And please explain why a `dpkg --reconfigure -a` and `sudo apt-get update` in any way should help after removing the lock-file.

Comment: update command is to check if the lock is removed.